# Calendar in Modal - Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-4

I would like to add a calendar to my booking form which is in modal. Because i am using modal, screen freezes in mobile view if i use calendar as modal (or popover...)too.

Is there any way to use calendar in different way?

My code is as below:

```
      <div class="modal-body">
        <select class="custom-select">
          <option selected>Customers</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6+</option>
        </select>

        <p>Pick a date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
        <script>
        $( function() {
          $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        } );
        </script>
```

Comment: you should update your question with some more details like screenshot of the issue or whatever you think can help

Answer (score 0):

There many plugins available for datepicker using jquery or javascript. But if you want in modal form using bootstrap. You can check link example below. It can give you insight how to do the flow.

[Sample code](http://shorturl.at/jopN8)
Happy coding.